# Very simple slideshow for someone new to html

Tags: slideshow

I'm new to HTML and CSS. I want a simple, responsive slideshow of around five images that automatically rotate and have next and previous controls. Ideally I'd like to have a line of HTML text on top of the images (is this possible?).

Any ideas? I've seen mention of javascript and jQuery but don't have a clue what they are.

Thank you

Comment: slimbox ? http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2#features

Answer (score 0):

[Lightbox 2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) is a good solution for you.

Just download the package and then add the js and css files as the website tells you. Then just put the images like:

```
<a href="img/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">image #2</a> 
<a href="img/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">image #3</a> 
<a href="img/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">image #4</a>
```

It's quite easy and you don't have to manipulate javascript or jquery.

Comment: Thanks. I've had a look and I'm not sure this is what I want. I need the slideshow to be part of the page not on top of the page. Can Lightbox 2 do this?

Comment: No, it can't, you need a carroussel so. I thought it was it.